# How to Output Array from Recursive PHP 7 Function without Array to String Error

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I researched several Stack Overflow posts which seemed good, but didn't offer me the fix to my issue. I'm created a tree walker function with PHP 7 that recursively loops through all nodes until it hits a leaf. I believe hitting the "leaf" qualifies as "stop condition"(?)

Anyway the function processTree() takes three arguments: an array, a start depth level, and finally an options array which is really the only way I could figure to collect output at each depth level.

Here is basically what the function should do. I pass it an associative array with three dimensions. The array consists of bible verses structured like so:

```
$verses['book_name']['chapter_num']['verse_num'] = $verse_text
```

##### Demo $verses array:

```php
$verses['Jeremiah'][29][11] = 'For I know the thoughts that I think toward you, saith the LORD, thoughts of peace, and not of evil, to give you an expected end.';
$verses['John'][3][16] = 'For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.';
$verses['Romans'][8][28] = 'And we know that all things work together for good to them that love God, to them who are the called according to his purpose.';
$verses['John'][1][1] = "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.";
$verses['John'][1][3] = "All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.";
```

Here is what my function looks like now:

##### Function: processTree():

```php
function processTree($tree, $lev=0, $options=[]) {
   $markup = '';
   $out_arr = [];

   foreach ($tree as $branch => $twig) {

      // Debug
      // If twig is verse text
      if (!is_array($twig)) {
         echo '<p><strong>Twig:</strong> ' . $twig . '</p>';
      }
      
      $markup .= '<li>';
      $cur_depth = $lev+1;

      if (is_array($twig)) {
         // if node
         echo '<p><strong>Branch:</strong> ' . $branch . '</p>';
         $options[$cur_depth] = $branch;
         $markup .= "<h$cur_depth>" .$branch. "</h$cur_depth>" . processTree($twig, $cur_depth, $options);
      } else {
         // if leaf
         $options[$cur_depth] = $branch;
         $markup .= "<h$cur_depth>" .$branch. "</h$cur_depth>" . $twig;
      }
      
      $markup .= var_dump($options);
      $markup .= '</li>';
      
   
   } // /END foreach

   $markup = '<ul>' . $markup . '</ul>';
   $out_arr['markup'] = $markup;
   $out_arr['results'] = $options; 
   
   return $out_arr;
}

// Since default values are defined for args 2 and 3 they are not needed here
echo processTree($verses);
```

The function sort of worked when I was outputting a string ($markup), but when I tried to change it to an output an array, it gives me "**Array to String conversion error**". I suspect it has to do with the processTree() call in the "if (is_array($twig))" section, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

#### DESIRED OUTPUT:

Given the three variables $book_name, $chapter_num, and $verse_num I should be able to either get/set the $verse_text; this works. But, I'm having trouble storing this info when I'm sequentially looping through the array. Imagine I didn't know what all verses were contained in the array. I want to loop through the array tree and in the end print something like this:

```
$result = processTree($verses);
var_dump($result);

// Output:
// Here are the rows/verses stored in array $verses:

Jeremiah 29:11
John 1:1
John 1:3
John 3:16
Romans 8:28
```

In the function I am able to store the three individual values to build that list of strings, but I can't seem to figure out how to build them into strings, and keep the three from overwriting the previous three. I think the problem is with maintaining state (or "statefulness"?). ***Looking for the most elegant way to solve this.*** I hope this makes sense, if not, ask and I will try to clarify.

#### RESOURCES:

Here are the URLS that I researched before posting:

- [How to return array from recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427397/how-to-return-array-from-recursive-function/15427448)
- [PHP: Return an array from recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065866/php-return-an-array-from-recursive-function)
- [PHP: recursively convert array to string if key has a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391859/php-recursively-convert-array-to-string-if-key-has-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your issue correctly, but if you know that you only ever have exactly three dimensions to your array then you don't need recursion, just nested iteration:

```
foreach ($data as $book => $chapters) {
    foreach ($chapters as $chapter => $verses) {
        foreach ($verses as $verse => $text) {
            printf("%s %d:%d\n", $book, $chapter, $verse);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jeremiah 29:11
John 3:16
John 1:1
John 1:3
Romans 8:28
```

If you want that as an array:

```
$list = [];
foreach ($data as $book => $chapters) {
    foreach ($chapters as $chapter => $verses) {
        foreach ($verses as $verse => $text) {
            $list[] = sprintf('%s %d:%d', $book, $chapter, $verse);
        }
    }
}
print_r($list);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Jeremiah 29:11
    [1] => John 3:16
    [2] => John 1:1
    [3] => John 1:3
    [4] => Romans 8:28
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! This looks like the exact elegant-type solution I was hoping for! But, can you confirm for me this: Are you saying that a recursive solution is not best for this application, OR are you saying that I can't return an array in my function because it is recursive? In this case I know that the depth will only ever be 3, but just in general for other applications -- I'm just trying to learn recursion and getting better bit-by-bit. Thanks!

Comment: To elaborate, let's say I had seven dimensions. Even though my dimensions are finite, wouldn't that be unwieldy and inelegant to have seven nested loops?

Comment: _"Are you saying"_ I'm saying that recursion is like regex -- it adds unnecessary complexity that you should avoid if you easily can. You certainly could return an array, but the alternate solution is much simpler. _"wouldn't that be unwieldy and inelegant to have seven nested loops"_ Yep probably.

Answer (score 0):

At the last line you are returning empty array which you are appending in the recursive call. You should either make the function return void, return the whole text or call the function by itself since it is echoing the text itself and not appending it as a text.

//edit: like this:

```
function processTree($tree, $lev=0, $options=[]) {
   $markup = '';
   $out_arr = [];

   foreach ($tree as $branch => $twig) {

      // Debug
      // If twig is verse text
      if (!is_array($twig)) {
         echo '<p><strong>Twig:</strong> ' . $twig . '</p>';
      }
      
      $markup .= '<li>';
      $cur_depth = $lev+1;

      if (is_array($twig)) {
         // if node
         echo '<p><strong>Branch:</strong> ' . $branch . '</p>';
         $options[$cur_depth] = $branch;
         $markup .= "<h$cur_depth>" .$branch. "</h$cur_depth>" . processTree($twig, $cur_depth, $options);
      } else {
         // if leaf
         $options[$cur_depth] = $branch;
         $markup .= "<h$cur_depth>" .$branch. "</h$cur_depth>" . $twig;
      }
      
      $markup .= var_dump($options);
      $markup .= '</li>';
      
   
   } // /END foreach

   $markup = '<ul>' . $markup . '</ul>';
}

// Since default values are defined for args 2 and 3 they are not needed here
processTree($verses);
```

Comment: Yes, it originally just returned the $markup string, but I decided to change it to return an array like this `$out_arr['markup'] = $markup;` and that is what was throwing the "Array to String Conversion" error I mentioned, so I tested to see if it would be the same with an empty array. I'll update the code with a comment to reflect this.